# CryptAcquireContext and CryptDeriveKey x64 mode

Tags: delphi, encryption

Delphi Xe4. Test on Win7Pro x64, Win8Ent x64, WinSrv2012;

```
Const

CGuAdvapi32dll=WinApi.Windows.Advapi32;

CALG_MD2      = 32769;
CALG_MD4      = 32770;
CALG_MD5      = 32771;
CALG_SHA      = 32772;
CALG_SHA_1    = 32772; // CALG_SHA
CALG_SHA_256  = 32780;
CALG_SHA_384  = 32781;
CALG_SHA_512  = 32782;

CALG_DES      = 26113;
CALG_RC2      = 26114;
CALG_3DES     = 26115;
CALG_3DES_112 = 26121;
CALG_AES_128  = 26126;
CALG_AES_192  = 26127;
CALG_AES_256  = 26128;
CALG_AES      = 26128; // CALG_AES_256
CALG_RC4      = 26625;

PROV_RSA_AES = 24;        // The PROV_SSL provider type supports US AES crypto-algorithm
CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT = $F0000000;


{S} Function GuCryptAcquireContext(hProv: PULong; Container: LPCTSTR; Provider: LPCTSTR; ProvType: DWord; Flags: DWord): Bool; StdCall; External CGuAdvapi32dll Name 'CryptAcquireContextW';
{S} Function GuCryptReleaseContext(hProv: ULong; Flags: DWord): Bool; StdCall; External CGuAdvapi32dll Name 'CryptReleaseContext';
{S} Function GuCryptCreateHash(hProv: ULong; AlgId: ULong; hKey: ULong; Flags: DWord; Hash: PULong): Bool; StdCall; External CGuAdvapi32dll Name 'CryptCreateHash';
{S} Function GuCryptHashData(hHash: ULong; Data: PByte; DataLen: DWord; Flags: DWord): Bool; StdCall; External CGuAdvapi32dll Name 'CryptHashData';
{S} Function GuCryptDeriveKey(hProv: ULong; AlgId: ULong; hData: ULong; Flags: DWord; Key: PULong): Bool; StdCall; External CGuAdvapi32dll Name 'CryptDeriveKey';
{S} Function GuCryptDestroyHash(hHash: ULong): Bool; StdCall; External CGuAdvapi32dll Name 'CryptDestroyHash';
{S} Function GuCryptDestroyKey(hKey: ULong): Bool; StdCall; External CGuAdvapi32dll Name 'CryptDestroyKey';
```

...

```
Procedure Test64;
var   hProv, hKey, hHash: Ulong; key:string; CGuSoC:dword;
begin
  key:='my test password';CGuSoC:=sizeof(char);
  if not GuCryptAcquireContext(@hProv, nil, nil, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT) then MessageBox(0, 'Not CAC', 0, 0);
   MessageBox(0, PChar(IntToStr(hprov)), 0, 0); // < --- 1 check !
  if not GuCryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD2{MD5, SHA}, 0, 0, @hHash) then MessageBox(0, 'Not CCH', 0, 0);
  if not GuCryptHashData(hHash, @key[1], Length(key)*CGuSoC, 0) then MessageBox(0, 'Not CHD', 0, 0);
  if not GuCryptDeriveKey(hProv, CALG_RC4{RC2, AES}, hHash, 0, @hKey) then MessageBox(0, 'Not CDK', 0, 0);
  if not GuCryptDestroyHash(hHash) then MessageBox(0, 'Not CDH', 0, 0);
   MessageBox(0, PChar(IntToStr(hprov)), 0, 0); // < --- 2 check !
  if not GuCryptDestroyKey(hKey) then MessageBox(0, 'Not CDK', 0, 0);
  if hProv=0 then MessageBox(0, 'hProv=0!', 0, 0) else if not GuCryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0) then MessageBox(0, 'Not CRC', 0, 0);
end;
```

Q: Compile with target platforms "32-bit windows", all Ok. In check string 1 and 2 show big numeric ID, ex. 882345.

Compile with target platforms "64-bit windows", working ok, but show "0" in check 2 (check 1 = ok, big num). **Why?**

p.s. I change hProv variable type to ULong64 (in proc.Test64 var. and GuCryptAcquireContext define), but no result.

Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: Please supply an SSCCE. What on earth made you decide to reinvent every single Windows type? How are we expected to know what they are. Don't do that.

Comment: Yes, I forgot. Corrected the text above.

Comment: No, I want an SSCCE. I want a program that I can paste into my compiler that compiles and runs. Please don't make me spend the time to try and make it. That's your job.

Comment: Understood. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's a lot better. Perfect would be a complete console app program that I could just paste. It starts `program` and finished `end.` That's what I mean by SSCCE. Anyway, I've solved your problem as you can see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that you have translated [`HCRYPTPROV`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382471.aspx), [`HCRYPTKEY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382468.aspx) and [`HCRYPTHASH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382465.aspx) as 32 bit integers. But they are actually pointer sized integers. You should declare them as `NativeUInt`.

There are also other more minor problems with your translation. My comments:

- Don't invent your own types, use the types declared in the Windows unit.
- Don't rename Windows API functions. If the function is called `CryptEncrypt` in the Windows API, you should use that name also. Doing otherwise leads to confusion.
- Don't be too literal in your translations. Be prepared to use `var` parameters rather than pointers. For example the first parameter to `CryptAcquireContext` would be better as a `var` parameter.

My final recommendation would be to use an existing translation of the API, one that is tried and tested. I expect you will find one in the JEDI code. That said, I despair of the JEDI project and their inability to make it discoverable.